# Indexpath.row incremented by two values not one

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, indexpath

Is it possible for tableview to skip an indexPath in cellForRowAt delegate? My logic is based on that the indexPath will always be incremented by one (because there will always be one cell on the screen). Should I change my logic[image: terminal screenshot]?

Status is 1 or -1 based on the scroll direction. but it should never change to 2 which you can see in the second last line.

Comment: indexpath is uniform

Comment: it always increment by 1

Comment: so what could be the reason? and It didn't happen only one time it keeps happening.

Comment: It is very difficult to say what the issue is as you haven't shown the code that produces this output. It is important to note that you should never rely on the order in which `cellForRow` will be called in relation to the `indexPath`.  It is perfectly normal and possible for it to be called for row 4 and then for row 6.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve `willDisplayCell` might be a better delegate call to use.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh indexPath.row can be incremented by 2.  Actually I am saving the old indexPath every time the cellForRow is called. I noticed when there is a difference of two in between these two variables.

Comment: you are saying that in willDisplayCell indexPath will always be incremented by 1?

Comment: It's not that it can be incremented by two, as such.  It is that each call to that method should be considered a separate event and you should not rely on any specific order to those calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213675/discussion-between-paulw11-and-hassan-khan).